# How To Show Chechbox Result From Metabox To Single Post Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ask to everyone, i have problem. Here i try to use multiple chechbox to my custom post metabox.

```
<?php

    function prodetail() {
        add_meta_box('pro_metabox', 'Detail Property', 'pro_metabox', 'property', 'normal', 'default');
    }

    function pro_metabox() {
        global $post;
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
        wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

        $postmeta = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'elements', true ) );


            $elements = array(
                'pool' => 'Pool',
                'garage' => 'Garage',
                'balcon' => 'Balcon',
                'yard' => 'Yard',
                'internet' => 'Internet'
            );

            foreach ( $elements as $id => $element) {
                if ( is_array( $postmeta ) && in_array( $id, $postmeta ) ) {
                    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                } else {
                    $checked = null;
                }
                ?>

                <div class="pro-inn">
                    <div class="procols"> 
                        <div class="pro-inn">
                            <input  type="checkbox" name="multval[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
                            <?php echo $element;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php 

            }
    }


    function pro_meta($post_id, $post) {
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post->ID;
        }

        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
            return $post->ID;

        if ( ! empty( $_POST['multval'] ) ) {
               update_post_meta( $post_id, 'elements', $_POST['multval'] );
            } else {
                delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'elements' );
        }

    }
    add_action('save_post', 'pro_meta', 1, 2); 

?>
```

help me to add code to show this checked result to single.php because my code use foreach just show Array text not show text like Pool Garage Balcon ect.

Thanks

Comment: seems metabox value stored wrong in DB. can post your save post code?

Comment: @vel thanks for anwser, please cek my complete code (edited).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your single.php file for your custom post

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'elements', true );
foreach($meta_value as $key=>$value){
    echo  $value . ' ';
}
```

It will show results same as you mentioned in the question ie:

(Pool Garage Balcon ect.)